# Getting values when NSDictionary contains a list

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary, enumerate, unrecognized-selector

I am being passed a dictionary:

```
aDictionary
```

When I log it out the dictionary has the following format:

```
{
 value1 = "subValue1 {label=value1, info1=, info2=}";
 value2 = "subValue2 {label=value2, info1=, info2=}";
 value3 = "subValue3 {label=value2, info1=, info2=}";
 }
```

I need to iterate over the dictionary and then determine if there is a value for value3 -> subValue3 -> info2.

I can do the initial iteration and I can make a subdictionary of the line:

```
"subValue3 {label=value2, info1=, info2=}"
```

But when I try to use it, say to get a count of the keys, I get -[subValue3 allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

```
NSArray *keys;
int i, count;
id key, value;

keys = [aDictionary allKeys];
count = [keys count];
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    key = [keys objectAtIndex:i];
    value = [aDictionary objectForKey:key];
    NSLog (@"Key: %@ for value: %@", key, value);

    NSDictionary *subDictionary = [aDictionary objectForKey:key];
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"info2"]) {
        DLog(@"subDictioanry = %@", subDictionary);
        // Everything is fine up to here
        NSArray *keys2;
        int i2, count2;
        id key2, value2;

        keys2 = [subDictionary allKeys];
        count = [keys2 count];
        //
        // Right here I get "-[subValue3 allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"
        //
        for (i2 = 0; i2 < count2; i2++) {
            key2 = [keys2 objectAtIndex:i2];
            value = [subDictionary objectForKey:key];
            DLog (@"Key: %@ for value: %@", key2, value2);

            NSDictionary *subDictionary2 = [subDictionary objectForKey:key2];
            DLog(@"subDictionary2 = %@", subDictionary2);
        }
    }
```

Questions:
I am not sure what the format of that second group of values is ("subValue3 {label=value2, info1=, info2=}").  Is it a set, an array, a dictionary?
How do I get that group into a dictionary (without failing on the key(?) "subValue3") so that I can check if the key info2 has any value?

Disclaimers:
I know there are more efficient ways to iterate over a dictionary, I'm just trying to be as clear as possible.
I'm sure there is just something basic I'm missing but I am not seeing the answer in the Apple docs on iteration or NSDictionary nor am I finding anything about the format in that second group.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

right now `"subValue1 {label=value1, info1=, info2=}";` is a `NSString`. So `allKeys` of a `NSString` will crash.

Infact does this `"subValue1 {label=value1, info1=, info2=}";` look like a valid json. I dont think this is a valid JSON. Even [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) thinks so.

This is a valid json

```
{
    "subValue1": {
        "label": "value1",
        "info1": "",
        "info2": ""
    }
}
```

After you construct json like so, then use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert -

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

if (!jsonDict) 
{
  NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
} else 
{
   for(NSDictionary *item in jsonDict) 
      NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
}
```

Comment: True.  But I don't want to go through the process of converting it to JSON just so I can get the value.  Perhaps I need to just parse it as a string.

Comment: if you dont want to convert the JSON then you could use regular expressions.